# Network Boot via Ansible

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ansible, kickstart

Environment - I've installed Ansible and using its vSphere_Guest API. This is connecting to my vSphere and successfully creating a virtual machine. I already have a satellite server with kickstart, configured with cobbler, which perfectly installs RHEL.

Problem - I want to install operating system on the VM created using Ansible. vSphere_Guest API could start the VM using an ISO but not by network. How can I start that newly created VM via Network ? I don't see any option to start VM via Network.

Comment: What do you mean by _"option to start VM via Network"_? Every VM will boot from network if there is no other boot media (removable,hdd,cd).

Comment: I never tried it without a CD ROM. I just did and now it worked fine. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comment:

> Every VM will boot from network if there is no other boot media (removable,hdd,cd)

It is default VM BIOS settings.